# are controllers model specific or action specific?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

Let's say you have the following.

```
Manager model
Request model
User model

A user makes a request. The manager then approves that request (or denies it).
```

So my question is: does the approve/deny method go in the Request controller or Manager controller? Or maybe it does not matter?

The manager does the "action" but in the background we are updating the model. It could be as something as simple as changing a string.

I've done this both ways and being more model specific seems more natural to me, but I want to do this the right way as I still haven't worked on a ton of projects.

Comment: Actually I would actually go for a fourth entity - Approvals. A manager approves a request by `POST /requests/:request_id/approvals`. But I think you're thinking about the problem wrong. REST is resource oriented - so its oriented around resources and performing actions on those.

Comment: Your controllers correspond to resources or even a resource in a specific context.

Comment: If you were forced to work with these three models does the question not make sense in the rails world? I am trying to avoid introducing a new model, but what you said makes good sense and maybe it is unavoidable.

Comment: Adding an additional model is not a bad thing - having parts that do a single job (in this case keeping track of who approved what and when) is generally preferable to lumping things into large classes.

Comment: Thanks max. Fast and good response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:employee, :manager]
  has_many :applications, foreign_key: 'applicant_id'
end

class Application < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :applicant, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :approvals
end

class Approval < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :application
  belongs_to :manager, class: 'User'
  validates_uniqueness_of :application_id, scope: 'manager_id'
end
```

Note `Application` instead of `Request`. `Request` and `Response` are problematic as model names since they are core concepts in Rails and web development in general. Using the instance variable `@request` for example will mask the incoming request! It also makes your code very hard to reason about.

Note that you probably don't need a separate manager model unless the requirements are wildly different. You can solve it by using [roles](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) instead.

We then setup a nested route:

```
resources :applications do
  resources :approvals, only: [:create, :destroy], shallow: true
end
```

And a controller to CRUD approvals:

```
class ApprovalsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!   
  before_action :authorize! 
  before_action :set_application, only: [:new, :create, :index]  

  # Approve an application
  # POST /applications/:application_id/approvals
  def create
    @approval = @application.approvals.new do |a|
      a.manager = current_user
    end
    if @approval.save
      redirect_to @application, success: 'Application Approved'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # Revoke approval
  # DELETE /approvals/:id
  def destroy
    @approval = Approval.find(params[:id])
    @approval.destroy
    redirect_to @approval.application, success: 'Approval revoked.'
  end

  private
  def set_application
    @application = Application.find(params[:application_id])
  end

  # Just a minimal authorization example
  # Use Pundit or CanCanCan for real world apps instead of reinventing the wheel
  def authorize!
    raise AuthorizationError unless current_user.manager?
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to write this all out. Learned a lot today :D. This helps a ton.